# os.environ not getting my environment variables

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, virtualenv

I have a simple python app with this file directory:

```
C:.
├───Sample Project
│   ├───project
│   │   ├───.vscode
│   │   ├───bin
│   │   ├───models
│   │   ├───projects
│   │   │   └───test
│   │   └───utils
│   └───venv
```

Inside `C:\Users\usr\Desktop\raicom\Sample Project\project` is my `project.env` which contains:

```
sample=hello
sample2=world
```

Inside `C:\Users\usr\Desktop\raicom\Sample Project\project\.vscode` is my `settings.json` which contains:

```
{
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/project.env"
}
```

Inside `C:\Users\usr\Desktop\raicom\Sample Project\project\projects\test` is a file named `test.py` which contains:

```
import os

print(os.environ.get('sample'))
print(os.environ.get('sample2'))
```

this should print my environment variables. When I run debug mode, it does just that.

[image]

but when I click Run Python File, it outputs None on both cases:

[image]

What could I be missing or doing wrong?

Follow up question, why is it working in debug mode but not in the run python file mode?

Comment: What level of folder are you opening in vscode? your launch. what does json look like? How you debug and run your code, showing the full picture of the terminal.

Comment: The description of your file structure is really unclear, Which is the file? Which is the folder? can you show it directly with screenshots?

Comment: @Alexander what do I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in debug mode because when you run it from debug mode the Current working directory is the project root directory, but when you right click and say run python file in terminal it runs it with the current working directory as the directory containing the python script.

When it is run with the current working directory as the python script directory it doesn't take into account your .vscode settings.

A solution is to use a module to load your .env file for example:  [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)

Answer (score 1):

Please use debug mode.

Environment variable definitions files can be used for scenarios such as **debugging** and tool execution (including linters, formatters, IntelliSense, and testing tools), but **aren't applied to the terminal**.

Read [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_environment-variables) for more details.